# What is the correct counter to translate 'One Piece'?

Tags: translation, word-choice, counters, anime

I was wondering whether the anime is actually called that way because it is hard to convey this meaning in japanese with a single word. For those who are not aware, One Piece is the greatest treasure in the world buried in one place, so it is probably something huge and not having clear bounds.

> 富、名声、力。この世の全てを手に入れた男、海賊王、ゴールド・ロジャー。彼の死に際に話った一言は人々を海へかり立てた。「俺の財宝か？欲しけりゃくれてやる。探せ！この世の全てをそこに追いてきた。」

Can we translate 'One Piece' to japanese better than 一個?

Comment: *One Piece* in this manga is always ワンピース in Japanese. Why do you want to "translate" it when it's originally a word coined in Japanese?

Comment: As @naruto said, there's no reason for translating a title originally coined in Japanese. But, if you really want to translate it, I would use 一つ rather than 一個, considering that the treasure is something indefinite in size and shape.

Comment: Well, 'translate' is probably a bad choice of wording, I am more like curious what it would be called in japanese if it wasn't called via an English word. I perfectly understand that any reasonable result could be used at best as an awkward pun, but it still makes sense for me to ask which counter Pieces would take if, say, Pirate King split his treasure in seven parts, or in any situation which is similar to One Piece (The Holy Grail, or any other mythical artifact)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am more like curious what it would be called in japanese if it wasn't called via an English word

Okay... ワンピース has been referred to as **ひとつなぎの大秘宝【だいひほう】**　(literally "unseparated great hidden treasure") several times, so you may think this is the official "Japanese translation".

[image]

一個 is just a mundane phrase used to count small objects, and it makes no sense as the name of a treasure. Basically it's very hard to talk about the correct counter for this "piece" since no one knows what it is like. Choosing a counter may give the readers a big hint of what it is like. For example, if we called it ひとかけらの秘宝 using a counter かけら ("particle", "fragment"), it would end up assuming *One Piece* is a tangible hard object that may break.  ひとつなぎ ("unseparated", "one big") is a clever word choice that avoids this problem.

Answer (score 1):

One Piece (ワンピース) is the proper and formal name of the titular object. It wouldn't make much sense to refer to it in any other way since, if you were referring to it from an in-universe perspective or discussing it with fans, any *other* reference wouldn't make sense for the conversation.